# How to customize ZfcUser module for impmenting in an existing module with extra elements in sign up

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I have tried ZfcUser module using its documentation on GitHub

https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser

Problem is I want to implement it on my existing project for Signup and Sign in and my database and signup page has many items in the form , while in ZfcUser implementation they have just implemented a very few items. How to customize and apply ZfcUser to an existing Project having front end already designed. I need to make changes in module of ZFC User to fit my needs. How is it possible ?

As you can see in screenshot it is having only 2 elements while my signup page needs at least 30 elements and my table is also different.

[image]

My Table in mysql has following structure :

```
    # Name Type Collation Attributes Null Default Extra
    1 userId varchar(50) No None
    2 appId varchar(50) No None
    3 active tinyint(2) Yes 0
    4 subscribed bit(1) Yes 0
    5 email varchar(100) Yes NULL
    6 deviceId varchar(255) No None
    7 imei varchar(100) Yes NULL
    8 mobile varchar(20) Yes NULL
    9 name varchar(255) Yes NULL
    10 os varchar(20) No None
    11 osversion varchar(10) Yes NULL
    12 appversion varchar(10) Yes NULL
    13 passwordHash varchar(600) Yes NULL
    14 registrationDate datetime No None
    15 salt double No None
    16 sim varchar(100) Yes NULL
    17 fbId varchar(100) Yes NULL
    18 innerCircleNo varchar(30) Yes NULL
    19 companyName varchar(100) Yes NULL
    20 currentTimezone varchar(10) Yes NULL
    21 countryCode varchar(3) Yes NULL
    22 countryName varchar(100) Yes NULL
    23 cityName varchar(50) Yes NULL
    24 currentCountryCode varchar(3) Yes NULL
    25 currentCountryName varchar(100) Yes NULL
    26 currentCityName varchar(50) Yes NULL
    27 textReadCount int(11) Yes 0
    28 textUnreadCount int(11) No 0
    29 richReadCount int(11) Yes 0
    30 richUnreadCount int(11) No 0
    31 designation varchar(60) Yes
    32 profilepic varchar(256) Yes NULL
    33 lastname varchar(128) Yes
    34 website varchar(128) Yes NULL
    35 role varchar(30) Yes NULL
    36 logincount int(4) Yes 0
    37 interests text Yes NULL
    38 facebook varchar(200) Yes NULL
    39 twitter varchar(200) Yes NULL
```

How to Customise the ZfcUSer to an existing project?. Sorry just new to ZF2 . Please help?

Comment: You can try create new forms, overwrite factory form -> "zfcuser_login_form" and "zfcuser_register_form" ( https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/1.x/Module.php ) in your module config. But there will be next problems with authentication and data recording. The best way is create your own custom module.

Comment: So you mean I create a new module and clone ZfcUser to it?

Comment: Write from scratch based on some idea of zfcuser.